# Display certain key value from a double array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have a mysql_fetch_assoc array inside of another array (has to be this way to pass as parameter for a requirement I am doing) and I am iterating the array using two foreach loops.

So here is a visual example of my array

```
Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [event_home_team] => Arsenal
              [event_away_team] => Chelsea
              [event_final_result] => 2 - 0
          )

  )
```

I am iterating the array like so (please note $result is the array)

```
foreach ($result as $tmpArray) {
     foreach($tmpArray as $key => $row) {
        echo "$row";  
     }
}
```

Please note the keys that start with event_ are columns in a table and the => values are from a row. The echo $row will echo the entire as such

```
Arsenal      Chelsea      2 - 0
```

How can I alter my for loops so I only grab the value from the event_final_result column?

Comment: Please look into what are array keys and array values.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I suppose `$tmpArray['event_final_result']`

Comment: If you want to use PHP you are going to have to get familiar with processing arrays and arrays of arrays

Comment: @u_mulder Wouldn't that need to be `$tmpArray[0]['event_final_result']` So in case there are more than one inner array I would leave the double loop in :)

Comment: No, author iterates over inner array too. I know, that's madness, but it is.

Comment: @u_mulder I see your point. WOOPS!! _I must get familiar with ARRAYS if I want to answer questions on PHP_ :):)

Answer (score 0):

One loop will do the trick.

```
foreach ($result as $a) {
    echo $a['event_home_team'] . ' ' 
        . $a['event_away_team'] . ' ' 
        . $a['event_final_result'];
}
```

RESULT

```
Arsenal Chelsea 2-0
```